# How can mock.assert_called_once() be told to accept any instance of an object?

Tags: python, mocking

I have some code which is calling Mock `assert_called_one_with()`.

```
  import mock
  with mock.patch.object(myfile.Sheet,  'WriteData', autospec=True) as mock_sheets:
    somefile.ExportToSheets(query, 'api_key', 'sheet_id', 'A1')
    mock_sheets.assert_called_once_with(myfile.Sheet(), 'A1', [('a', 'b'), (1, 2)])
```

As you can see, everything compares equally except for the object instance.

```
AssertionError: Expected call: \
WriteData(<myfile.Sheet object at 0x7f9d487923c8>, 'A1', [('a', 'b'), ('1', '2')])
Actual call: \
WriteData(<myfile.Sheet object at 0x7f9d47bafb38>, 'A1', [('a', 'b'), ('1', '2')])
```

How can I either

- tell assert_called_once_with() to ignore object identity, or
- perform a similar assertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mock.ANY will match any value

```
mock_sheets.assert_called_once_with(mock.ANY, 'A1', [('a', 'b'), (1, 2)])
```